# How are limits determined for systotic and diastotic blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure

I know that the upper limits for systotic/diastotic blood pressure are 120/80. What is the mathematics behind these numbers? I am curious because I did not find information regarding how the numbers are arrived at. I am not sure if the numbers are based on statistical study or is there a scientific basis for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

120/80 are not upper limits on blood pressure - many people have blood pressures far in excess of those numbers. Instead, these are numbers beyond which [studies have shown](http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/files/docs/guidelines/jnc7full.pdf) connections to negative health outcomes - heart disease, for example.

There is nothing magical about the numbers 120 or 80 besides their divisibility by 10; a blood pressure of 121/81 is no more risky than 120/80 than 122/82 is over 121/81. Because of this, drawing a hard line isn't possible - it's just a suggestion.

Typically, systolic pressures less than 130-135 aren't given any special consideration beyond normal advice to exercise and eat well, unless there are other conditions/risks. Guidelines from the [American Heart Association](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/Conditions/HighBloodPressure/PreventionTreatmentofHighBloodPressure/American-Heart-Association-backs-current-BP-treatments_UCM_459129_Article.jsp#.WA4muOgrLcs) and the UK's [NHS](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/nhs-health-check/pages/understanding-your-nhs-health-check-results.aspx#bp) are to consider treatment only for diastolic pressures above 140mmHg. There has been some disagreement about these precise limits, with some recommendations for lower targets, for example [here](https://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/health/health-topics/topics/hbp). Some of the disagreement seems to be the types of interventions - the guidelines to treat diastolic hypertension only above 140mmHg are mostly considering medications, whereas the guidelines to treat prehypertension are aiming for improved lifestyle: diet, exercise, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to a specific study that drew these numbers? I am not familiar with the literature around this. I am curious about the way the sampling is done and the statistical methods that helped that highlighted these number.

Comment: Some of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted.

Comment: Added references; for some of your questions about sampling etc, @randominstanceOfLivingThing, those questions might deserve their own topic